# How to host large files on Google-App-Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like my server that runs on Google App Engine to host large files such as audio scripts and images, is it possible to store them as a column in a database? If not, what mechanisms may I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) (currently available in Java, Python and Go).
2. [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) (currently available in Java, Python and PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Blobstore and GCS are most likely what your are looking for.

Both services are not covered by the GAE SLAs however. If you need that kind of reliability promise you're stuck with the GAE datastore.

You can put your files in a BLOB property of a datastore entity and serve it from there. Datastore entities have a size limit of 1MB however.

To circumvent that, you must split and re-assemble your files using multiple entities. There again is a size limit to any GAE response which is 32MB.