# google app engine on this project (if possible) with low cost advice

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a simple website which fetch data, store data in csv and then populate it on the website.

website feature:

1. Password protected website
2. store data in csv files and then populate that data on the web browser on the request.
3. fetch data using ajax or php script and store  data in csv for later use.
4. update data in csv file, or delete and replace with a new csv file.
5. host php files, csv, javascript, css, image.

So my question is:

1. can it be hosted on google app engine?
2. do I need any kind of data storage that google cloud offer? (cloud sql, cloud storage, cloud datastore). I'm not sure if app engine can store csv file, and don't need database storage.
3. what google cloud feature should I use to make it a lowest cost? prefer lowest cost or free since it is not a profit website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be hosted on GAE but with a different way to approach it. For what your doing:

1. Password protected website: There are a few ways to do this. 
   A) Easiest is to let Google do it using their user [service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers) or other options can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth). You can do it locally using the datastore as well.
2. store data in csv files and then populate that data on the web browser on the request: Theres no need for CSV's in GAE. The biggest advantage to using GAE is its scalability which is lost if 50 instances try and access your CSV and get file lock errors. GAE has something called a Datastore that allows you to store whatever info you want in a non relational database. So instead of a row in the CSV you have a datastore entity. If all your data is already in a CSV you can easily import it.
3. fetch data using ajax or php script and store data in csv for later use: You can use PHP, Python, Java or Go currently to access the CSV but as I said in 2 you should look at the datastore.
4. update data in csv file, or delete and replace with a new csv file: Through the drive you can manipulate the CSV all you want, but see above
5. host php files, csv, javascript, css, image: You can host any files you want. Be it from the apps directory  or ideally the [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/). If its from the directory it has to be pushed when deploying the website. For the blobstore its dynamic and can be added or manipulated at any time.

All this can be done for free, all the listed services have free quotas availbale. Youll only need to pay if your website takes off.

For your second question, I would recomend (based off your desc) looking into Datastore and Blobstore.

You last question. If its somethign that will only have a limited traffic, or even just efficiently coded it should be free. When you hit your [quota](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas) it throws errors so youll never be charged (but keep that in mind when coding to handle them) [For pricing see here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing)

Comment: The files in google app engine is not writable right? If  I put cvs in there, I can't use php script to modify it right? I can't even delete csv and replace it with another csv using php script right? Only google cloud datastore has free quote right? Thanks

Comment: From the directory no: https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java?csw=1#writefile but if you want to use a CSV you can store in in a Google Drive or Blobstore. You can then download it, manipulate as needed then send it back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671252/create-csv-file-and-save-to-blobstore. TBH its a lot of extra work. To make your life easier put the upload the CSV into the Datastore then work from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 99.999% of my operation is to delete the csv and replace it with a new one. So datastore still a better way?

Comment: Without knowing what your doing exactly its hard for me to say yes or no.

Comment: my current operation locally is, download csv file, and then replace the old one if exist. and then display it on the browser. I am in process to create a php script that will do the downloading for me, and replacing the old file automatically. database/datastore is nice, but unless I need it, and it will be easier for me to upgrade in the future. I dont want to rewrite the code again. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you do any actual work on the CSV? Or is is simply a CVS repository? The Datastore would only be useful if your doing work to the data in the CSV. If its a repository then the Blobstore is your best bet. It simply stores any type of file. So you could DL from a site, check if there's a CSV with the same name, replace if needed then display.

Comment: Sinply a csv repository. I just check how old the file or the data, then simple replace the file with the new set if the condition match. That is all for current function. But all this is done automatically using php script.

Comment: Then you don't need the datastore for now. The blobstore is perfect for this.

Comment: is blobstore available for PHP, I can't find any information regarding to it, and this thread said no http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356578/how-to-host-large-files-on-google-app-engine/25356951#25356951

Comment: You are right :( Looks like Cloud Storage would work https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#deleting_files